# NavigationPage/Bar breaking on rapid back press (Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.848062)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently experiencing a strange issue with one of my pages which has `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">` (I've even tried `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` in the constructor with no success.

So, the navigation bar is not visible which is exactly what I expect, it is also the first page in my NavigationStack. If a user navigates to the search page, they have the option to bring back all items in the database - this will show a loading screen which I use a DependencyService for (which I found [here](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/build-your-own-transparent-page-from-scratch-for-xamarin-forms/) and [here](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/build-your-own-transparent-page-from-scratch-for-xamarin-forms/)). This acts as an overlay loading screen.

When the loading screen is displayed if the user were to rapidly tap the "Back" button as expected the gesture is blocked because of the loading screen, once the loading screen disappears if the user is still tapping the back button, it goes back; again as expected.

At this point - everything is happening as expected, everything looks fine. But following this sequence a bug is now about to happen. If the user navigates to ANY page and goes back to the menu page my app breaks. The navigation bar is displayed, scroll is disabled and if I were to sign out which does `App.Current.MainPage = new Navigationpage(new LoginPage());` the app will crash.

I am completely miffed why this is happening but I can replicate it without fail. If I follow the same sequence but I do not rapidly tap the back button - no issues happen. I sense this could be related to loading a large amount of items to the ListView, but I'm unsure yet.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

**Update**
This is the exception I am getting.

at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer+ParentingViewController.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00006] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:1002 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Dispose () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:147 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x0001f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:256 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Dispose () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:147 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.DisposeHelpers.DisposeModalAndChildRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element view) [0x0009f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\DisposeHelpers.cs:43 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CleanUpPages () [0x00017] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:564 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlatformRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\PlatformRenderer.cs:110 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Dispose () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:147 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00013] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:72 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.System.IDisposable.Dispose () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:58 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate.UpdateMainPage () [0x00022] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\FormsApplicationDelegate.cs:181 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate.ApplicationOnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) [0x00012] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\FormsApplicationDelegate.cs:142 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:211 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:359 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Application.set_MainPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page value) [0x0008b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:87 
  at OCS.iOS.AppDelegate.DidEnterBackground (UIKit.UIApplication uiApplication) [0x00054] in C:\TFS\Projects\Mobile\OCS\v2-branch\OCS\OCS.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:63 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.3.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at OCS.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\TFS\Projects\Mobile\OCS\v2-branch\OCS\OCS.iOS\Main.cs:9

Comment: You can provide the full code in your project which will contains the issue so that people can help you better . And what is the version of Xamarin.forms in your project?

Comment: I'll create a sample project with this bug and upload that - I'll update the title with the XF version. It's 4.2.0.848062

Comment: OK, I will check it as soon as possible after you uploading it .

Comment: Apologies for the disappearance, I've been busy at work. I created a sample project but had no success replicating the issue. I have however managed to get a exception to show now which seems to point to Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage - I've yet to make sense of this yet though. I've added the exception to my original post.

Comment: You could share your sample and I will test it on my side .